# Multiple NFTs from the same source

Tags: cryptocurrency, nft

General NFT question, but don't flame me, I really tried to find the answer.

Could NFT be created from the same image or copy of this image?

For example, take this NFT Lion Cat that I created:
https://rarible.com/token/0x60f80121c31a0d46b5279700f9df786054aa5ee5:1200950?

Can someone download the image and create an NFT from it?

I mean, isn't it part of the idea that this is original content by me and I have the copyrights for it?

In the Image area, you got the RAW image that proves you took this picture, nobody but the photographer has this RAW image. But to create this image NFT I didn't have to provide it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Could NFT be created from the same image or copy of this image?*

> *Can someone download the image and create an NFT from it?*

Yes to both questions. It is technically possible to create multiple NFTs that all represent the same image. They can be placed in the same collection, as well as across multiple collections.

As NFTs basically contain links to this image, it's not possible to prevent someone from creating a link to a public resource, i.e. from creating another NFT representing the same image.

---

> *I mean, isn't it part of the idea that this is original content by me and I have the copyrights for it?*

The [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard mostly defines just the technical specifications. But it doesn't really cover the licensing, ownership/authorship of the underlying resource, and other non-technical topics.

An NFT only proves ownership of the token - not copyrights of the image. Also, it proves ownership by an address - not by a person. Because there can be zero to multiple people holding a private key to the same address (holding the NFT representing the image).