# is two different ERC721 contract can mint same NFT

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

I'm learning blockchain development recently and I'm
implementing ERC721 contract to mint NFT and store the mapping of ownership. What if I deploy a second contract which mints NFT using same characteristics, does it have different NFTs or it will be replication of NFTs on the blockchain? Also, is there a possibility of minting same NFTs on the blockchain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple NFTs from the same source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816228/multiple-nfts-from-the-same-source)

Answer (score 1):

absolutely not, even if you are forking an existing contract (i.e. a replica), the contracts will be completely separate from each other, the ownership mapping of your contract will be completely different from that of the already existing contract

Comment: for e.g me and my friend mint NFT with same image using  original contract and replica contract then there will be two NFT according to both contract so how the uniqueness is valid on blockchain you can see the scenario here https://ibb.co/wzjSJbC

Comment: the 1st contract is made by someone, the 2nd it's made by someone else, so you know what's the original contract, also the address of the contract is unique.
you can make the replica of an NFT, but it will not be the original one, like you can buy a replica of Mona Lisa, but it will not be the original one

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be considered as replication. You can make many copies of the same images and characteristics. With the same image and same characteristics, you will be creating the same Nft.

> Also, is there a possibility of minting same NFTs on the blockchain?

Yes, I think if you go rarible and mint an Nft, you have an option to create as many copies as you want.